# Remove metadata from Office documents stored in SharePoint

Tags: microsoft-word, metadata, sharepoint-2010

Can anyone suggest a way of removing metadata, en masse, from Word and Excel documents that are stored in SharePoint 2010?

There are several thousand documents, each in their own folder (don't ask...) and ideally, I would be able to pick and choose which data is removed - much like an MP3Tag editor.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: For anyone coming to this question, a solution is available here: http://www.digitalconfidence.com/BatchPurifier.html